# How to get values from dynamically created elements using jquery in code behind

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, dynamic, webforms

Hi and thanks for taking the time to asnwer my question.

I have the following problem. I have a form and a button which says "add new activities".

Whenever the button is clicked I add a new set of elements, namely 2 drop down menus + text area. How can I get the values of these newly created elements in code behind since I cannot know their ids up front?

If there is something unclear about my question, please let me know.

Thanks again!

Comment: Can you show your code and explain it better ?

Comment: I have not code.. I was thinking about how to go about it and ran into this problem.. I wrote what is happening on the form. A user clicks a button and a new <li> element is added to the form containing 2 ddls and a text area. there may be 100 such li elements depending on how many times a user clicks on the button. At the bottom there is a save button. When the save button is clicked i want to retrieve the values of the dynamically created ddls and textareas

Comment: @Dragan: How you adding elements?? Can you add a `css-class` at the same time when you adding elements??

Comment: I haven't written that script yet.. However I have done the exact same thing in Spring using jquery and it is pretty easy. TO answer your question @huMpty duMpty, YES, i can add css class to the newly created elements. Not only that I can but I must in order for all of them to look like the design

Comment: So, the first thing you have to do before ask for help is **TRY**.

Comment: It sounds like you're mixing front and back end in a way that ASP.Net wasn't designed for.  I'd suggest looking into ASP.Net AJAX, I think that's what you're after: http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/act.ashx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But you must be setting id's (more importantly - name attributes) of new elements using certain pattern. Use the same pattern in a loop in server-side code to get values from `Request.Form`. Provide a hidden input where you put the total count of items added for the server-side to know the upper bound of loop counter.

Comment: wow this is exactly what I was looking for.. In Spring I did it the same way.. all new elements had to have the same name attribute and I could get an array of the values of all elements with that name.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks so much. Accepted your answer

Answer (score 0):

You should set the ids when you create the elements if you plan to access them again
So if you this is your text area:

```
var textarea = document.createElement('textarea');
```

You can set the id to like this:

```
textarea.id = "taId";
```