# I want to get the ID of label using C# which is being created by jQuery on RunTime

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

First I will explain my scenario. 
I have asp.net menu (dynamically created menu) and now I want to place push notification just like Facebook on my each menu option. I have designed it using CSS and put a label using jQuery.

```
 if (res == "MenuIcons") {

                $(this.parentElement).addClass('Notification');
                var $label = $("<label  ID=\"notificationlbl" + i + "\" style=\"position: absolute; margin-top: 2%; margin-left: -3.1%; margin-right:-3.3%; z-index: 99; color: white; font-size: 9px; font-family: Verdana; letter-spacing: -1px;\">").text('99');
                $(this.parentElement.parentElement).append($label);

                i++;
            }
```

But I am totally confused that how to handle it using C# because I am unable to get the ID of the label created on run-time.

If you didn't understand please let me know and I will explain it more.

Comment: Hi, check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13768563/how-to-get-values-from-dynamically-created-elements-using-jquery-in-code-behind

Comment: I don't think it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you set a data attribute to each label, something like

```
var $label = $("<label data-element-type='notification' ID=\"notificationlbl" + i + "\" style=\"position: absolute; margin-top: 2%; margin-left: -3.1%; margin-right:-3.3%; z-index: 99; color: white; font-size: 9px; font-family: Verdana; letter-spacing: -1px;\">").text('99');
```

and then you can retrieve the whole collection with jQuery:

```
$("[data-element-type='notification']").each(function(){...});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding runat="server" attribute in your label tag. You label tag id won't be available until runtime. So what you can do is search for the controllers by the id of your label. In code behind you can do as following

```
foreach(Contol c in this.Controls)
{
          if(c.ID.contains("notificationlbl")
          {
              //your code
          }
}
```

Comment: It is giving "Server tag is not well formed" error when I am trying to add runat="server" on my label @NZeta520

Comment: You can't use double quote within double quote or single quote within single quote. You can only use single quote within double quote and so on. I suppose that's the issue causing server tag error.